# Can OS X Yosemite be run off of my usb drive on a PC

Tags: windows, macos, boot, usb

I have a flash drive with OS X Yosemite on it, and i know that on a PC in the one time boot manager, it allows you to boot the computer from an external drive. I am currently running my iMac off of this drive, because my hard drive died and i didn't want to pay for a new one, but can this flash drive boot on a PC too?

Comment: Short answer, no. Longer answer, not as it stands & also is off-topic for SE, as it is against Apple's EULA to install on non-Apple hardware.

Comment: This is like asking "If I strap a diesel gas tank to my non-diesel car, will it work?". As @Tetsujin points out, you need Apple h/w to run OSX unless you go the hackintosh route. And that's a TOTALLY different conversation.